Is "let loose" better than "let slip", when it comes to "dogs"?
Fromkin's Introduction to Linguistics says:

Language purists sometimes rail against back-formations and cite enthuse and
liaise [from enthusiasm and liaison) as examples of language corruption. However,
language is not corrupt; it is adaptable and changeable. Don’t be surprised to
discover in your lifetime that shevelled and chalant have infiltrated the English language (from disheveled and nonchalant) to mean “tidy” and “concerned,” and if it
happens do not cry “havoc” and let slip the dogs of prescriptivism; all will be well.

Is "let loose" better than "let slip", when it comes to "dogs", even if it is figurative?
Isn't "let slip" only applied to words and sentences?

This question invites opinions, so I have voted to close it.

In the answers to your previous question it was indicated that the phrase "let slip the dogs of war" is quoted directly from Shakespeare's Julius Caesar. Changing it would weaken the connection, even though "let slip" is today considered an archaic term (for releasing animals such as dogs).

Years ago (1980s) in England I knew a fellow who kept lurchers (dogs, a cross-breed between some kind of terrier and a 'long dog' such as a greyhound) and he used to (legally) take them rabbit hunting. He called releasing them to go after rabbits they they had seen or scented 'slipping' them. I would retain 'let slip' for releasing for some direct purpose, and 'let loose' for merely releasing dogs so that they can run around and be free.

Although I can imagine a householder loosing guard dogs because they heard a suspicious sound in the grounds.

To combine the two current answers:

If the goal is literary allusion, it's best to stick to the original wording insofar as it suits your sentence. You might even correct some common mis-quotes if you get the chance.
If the goal is current idiomatic conversation about letting dogs off their leash, you should abandon this Shakespearean construction entirely. "Let slip" is not in current usage; it would be something like "Let your dog off its leash." (Going back to allusion, a more modern one would be "Release the hounds!," meaning to set attack-trained guard dogs upon intruders. Probably not truly started by, but popularized by, Montgomery Burns of The Simpsons.)


slip is not the contemporary word for this action of releasing dogs from their leashes or cages, and you wouldn't typically hear "let loose the dogs" but instead "let the dogs loose" though you might well find "let loose the dogs" in writing.
